# Why does this element travel two different distances?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to move some elements in a predictable manner however I am getting unexpected results.

When you press the "Down" button once, then the "Up" button once the div does not return to its original location.

Why does the Y coordinate begin and end with a value of 29 when the element is clearly in two different places?

```
HTML
<button id='btn-up'>Up</button>
<button id='btn-down'>Down</button>
<span class='text'>Y coordinate: <span id="yCoord"></span></span>

<div id="myItem" class="moveItem"></div>


CSS
.text {
  font-family: arial;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#myItem {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.moveItem {
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
}


JAVSCRIPT
const pixelDistance = 50;
var currentY = $('#myItem').position().top;

$('#yCoord').text(currentY);

$("#btn-up").on('click', function() {
currentY = currentY - pixelDistance;

$('#myItem').css('transform', 'translateY(' + currentY + 'px)');

$('#yCoord').text(currentY);
});

$("#btn-down").on('click', function() {
currentY = currentY + pixelDistance;

    $('#myItem').css('transform', 'translateY(' + currentY + 'px)');

$('#yCoord').text(currentY);  
});
```

Reference code: https://jsfiddle.net/tsf9bz27/

Comment: Because the first time you start at `$('#myItem').position().top;`, which is not 0 but 29, the first move is 29+50 (if down) but the second is only 50. If you read here it explains why the first is what it is: https://api.jquery.com/position/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are retrieving top position and add it the translateY which will mess up the first move

```js
const pixelDistance = 50;
var currentY = $('#myItem').position().top;
var pos = 0;

$('#yCoord').text(currentY);

$("#btn-up").on('click', function() {
  currentY = currentY - pixelDistance;
    pos = pos - pixelDistance;

  $('#myItem').css('transform', 'translateY(' + pos + 'px)');

  $('#yCoord').text(currentY);
});

$("#btn-down").on('click', function() {
  currentY = currentY + pixelDistance;
    pos = pos + pixelDistance;

 $('#myItem').css('transform', 'translateY(' + pos + 'px)');
  
  $('#yCoord').text(currentY);  
});
```

```css
.text {
  font-family: arial;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#myItem {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn-up'>Up</button>
<button id='btn-down'>Down</button>
<span class='text'>Y coordinate: <span id="yCoord"></span></span>

<div id="myItem" class="moveItem"></div>
```

Comment: Doh such a blatant mistake. Thank you Chiller!

Answer (score 0):

You're only reading `currentY` at the start of your code, not on every click. So the original Y is applied on "up", not the current value.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of quirks that mess with your Y-value. Here's a modified fiddle that probably behaves as you expect: https://jsfiddle.net/c9wy3kjd/

1) The buttons and the "Y coordinate" text are sitting on top of your `<div>`. These items push the div down some distance. To fix this, I put the buttons and text in a container and absolutely positioned it to "remove it from the flow". If that doesn't make sense, read about [CSS positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning).

2) Browsers often inject a little margin into the `body` element of a page to keep the text away from the edges. That was adding about 8px to the Y-value. It's simple to remove, so I also added a `body { margin: 0 }` rule to remove that.